# Display pop up menu when icon button widget is clicked Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made an alert dialog where user can update their profile details. In that with image container there is icon button widget. What I want is that when user clicks icon button, pop up menu will display with add/remove image option. Here is my code for alert dialog:

```
showDialog<void>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Update details'),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0))),
      content: StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) { return Container(
          width: 400,
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          width: 100.0,
                          height: 100.0,
                          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              image: new DecorationImage(
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  colorFilter: new ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.darken),
                                  image: data != null ? MemoryImage(data) : AssetImage("web/icons/contactsDefaultImage.png")
                              )
                          )
                      ),
                      IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.edit), onPressed: () async {
                         //display option here
                         _showPopupMenu();
                      })
                    ]),
                Container(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'name'
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'email'
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );},
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Cancel'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(child: Text('Save'),
          onPressed: () {
          // save
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

I tried to user showMenu for that. But as the position has to be hard-coded I don't was to use it.
what I tried:

```
void _showPopupMenu() async {
await showMenu(
  context: context,
  position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(100, 100, 100, 100),
  items: [
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text("add"),
    ),
    PopupMenuItem(
      child: Text("remove"),
    ),
  ],
  elevation: 8.0,
);
```

}

Now, what i want to know is how can i display it where the icon-button is tapped (without hard-coding the value). And is there another way to do it .i.e without using showMenu.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what is you want? post your try

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the question

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can write a method like this and call it on your icon button's `onPressed`

```
showPopupMenu(){
    showMenu<String>(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(25.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0),  //position where you want to show the menu on screen
      items: [
        PopupMenuItem<String>(
            child: const Text('menu option 1'), value: '1'),
        PopupMenuItem<String>(
            child: const Text('menu option 2'), value: '2'),
        PopupMenuItem<String>(
            child: const Text('menu option 3'), value: '3'),
      ],
      elevation: 8.0,
    )
    .then<void>((String itemSelected) {

      if (itemSelected == null) return;

      if(itemSelected == "1"){
        //code here
      }else if(itemSelected == "2"){
        //code here
      }else{
        //code here
      }

    });
}
```

***Edit: (to show menu at the position where user tapped)***

We can have a method like so -

```
void showPopUpMenuAtTap(BuildContext context, TapDownDetails details) {
  showMenu(
    context: context,
    position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
      details.globalPosition.dx,
      details.globalPosition.dy,
      details.globalPosition.dx,
      details.globalPosition.dy,
    ),
    // other code as above
  );
}
```

and use it with `GestureDetector` like so -

```
GestureDetector(
  child: const Icon(Icons.menu),
  onTapDown: (details) => showPopUpMenuAtPosition(context, details),
);
```

Comment: tnks. But please see the question again

Comment: you need to call the method on `onPressed` like this.. `onPressed: _showPopupMenu`

Comment: I have done that but as the value for position is hardcoded I don'nt want to use it.

Comment: Also can i display it where i tapped the button without hardcoding the postion

Comment: are you found any solution about position @RahulSingh

Comment: @Adnanhaider, I have edited the answer to include how to show the menu where user taps.

Comment: If any of you came here to do this 'relative positioning' on onLongPress field. You must first send the details of the clicked position from onTapDown to some variable that you've declared first. Later, you can get details through this variable.

Answer (score 4):

Solution if you wish to re-use your button and not a Gesture detector:

Create a key and assign your button the key. Then:

```
TextButton(
          key: _accKey,
          text: "Account",
          onPressed: () {
            final RenderBox renderBox =
                _accKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final Size size = renderBox.size;
            final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

            showMenu(
                context: context,
                position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
                    offset.dx,
                    offset.dy + size.height,
                    offset.dx + size.width,
                    offset.dy + size.height),
                items: [
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      child: const Text('menu option 1'), value: '1'),
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      child: const Text('menu option 2'), value: '2'),
                  PopupMenuItem<String>(
                      child: const Text('menu option 3'), value: '3'),
                ]);
          }),
```

Comment: You can create key 
`GlobalKey _accKey = GlobalKey();`

Comment: As for computing Renderbox size using GlobalKey is discouraged, how to achieve with BuildContext. By the way, the solution works correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of options you can choose:

You can use:

1. [Banner](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Banner-class.html)
2. [Card](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)
3. [Dialog](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html)
4. [PopupMenuButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html)
5. Or even [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html)

I hope it will help

Comment: tnks for the suggestion but i have updated my question please review it.

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking to is showdialog and alertdialog.

```
Void<String> testdialog(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
            title: ....
```

Comment: tnks for the answer. I have updated my question pls see it again. I can not use alert dialog.